# How can I encode a URL to pass Percent (%) sign in Swift?

Tags: swift, url

I need a URL like this to work:

> https://somehost.gov/api/wtk_download.csv?api_key=DEMO_KEY&wkt=POINT(-104.23828125%252039.90973623454)&attributes=power&names=2009&interval=60&full_name=SampleUser&email=sample@email.com&affiliation=TestOrganization&reason=Dev

Code I used to generate the URL:

```
let wktStr: String = "POINT("+formattedX+"%"+formattedY+")"
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "somehost.gov"
components.path = "/api/wtk_download.csv"
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: "DEMO_KEY"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "wkt", value: wktStr),
    URLQueryItem(name: "attributes", value: "power"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "names", value: yearString),
    URLQueryItem(name: "interval", value: "60"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "full_name", value: "SampleUser"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "email", value: "sample@email.com"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "affiliation", value: "TestOrganization"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "reason", value: "Dev")

]

let url = components.url
print(url!)
print(url!.absoluteURL)
```

Prints:

> https://somehost.gov/api/wtk_download.csv?api_key=DEMO_KEY&wkt=POINT(-104.23828125%252039.90973623454)&attributes=power&names=2009&interval=60&full_name=SampleUser&email=sample@email.com&affiliation=TestOrganization&reason=Dev

The server host gives an error because the `POINT(-104.23828125%252039.90973623454)` has `%25` instead of just `%`.

How can I generate the item `POINT(-104.23828125%2039.90973623454)` which has just the `%`?

Comment: Your code looks correct. I strongly doubt that you're getting a server error "_because the URL has %25_" - encoding the % character as %25 is absolutely correct and necessary.

Comment: But when I remove the 25 from that URL and try it in Browser it works fine. If I try it as is with 25 it fails. It clearly says there is error in WKT POINT. So what is wrong then? This is the only way I can test and find out from Browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use the [Wind Toolkit Data API](https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/wind/wind-toolkit/wtk-download/). (Update as of Jan 2023: This is what the original link looked like at the time this question was written: [Wind Toolkit Data API](https://web.archive.org/web/20170513032008/https://developer.nrel.gov/docs/wind/wind-toolkit/wind-toolkit-extract/))

At the time you wrote this question, in one of their example requests, that page had a query parameter that looked like this:

```
wkt=POINT(-104.23828125%2039.90973623453719)
```

That `%20` is really just a [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) space character.

(It *is* kind of confusing how they showed a URL-encoded value for the `wkt` parameter, but not for other parameters whose values contain spaces like `full_name=Sample User` or `affiliation=Test Organization`, so it's understandable where the confusion comes from.)

Anyway, to fix the problem, just replace the `%` character in your `wktStr` with a space:

```swift
let wktStr: String = "POINT("+formattedX+" "+formattedY+")"
```

Comment: Amazing it worked. Thank you. The misleading thing is from browser it worked for 2039.90973623453719 and I thought that is real Y. I would have never guessed it otherwise

Comment: Yeah, using the browser to test URL requests is generally a bad idea. Use something like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) instead. Yeah I figured that couldn't be the real "Y" value since those values looked like coordinates to me, and 2039.9097 is not a valid latitude or longitude.